# How to Assign values to a List of Lists in scala using loops?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala so finding difficulty. can some one please guide me about how to initialize a list of lists using for loop?? I tried this:

```html
for(i <- 1 to N)
  {
    for(D <- 1 to Dimensions)
    {
  Population=List(List(D,i))
    }
```

but it is not working well

Comment: Why do you want to use loops? In Scala, you should avoid loops, when possible. Is another solution without loops also sufficent?

Comment: And can you give more Information what possible `N`, `Dimensions` might be, and how your list of lists should look after creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
val population: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(1,2,3,4,5) map { i =>
   List(11, 12, 13, 14, 15) map { D =>
     (D, i)
  }
}
```

Basically, if you start with a List you end up with a List.

Similarly, if you start with an IndexedSequence, you will end up with an IndexedSequence

```
val populationAsIndexedSeq: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]] = 1 to 5 map { i =>
  11 to 15 map { D =>
    (D, i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *assign* values to an existing `List`. That's not what the `List` type is good for and it would be very poor Scala style. What you can and should do, however, is *create* a new `List[List[Int]]` with all the needed elements.

```
val population:List[List[Int]] = for {
  i <- (1 to n).toList
  d <- 1 to dimension
} yield List(d,i)
```

The 1st `Range` (1 to n) is cast to `List` so that the result will be `List[List[Int]]`. Without it the result is `Seq[List[Int]]`.